# Windows Azure Virtual Machine with GoDaddy Custom Domains

Tags: azure, dynamic-dns, bindings

I asked this question ([on SO by accident](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20040025/550975)):

I am having problems setting up a custom domain (purchased on GoDaddy.com) with an Azure virtual machine (on which I plan on running multiple websites.) I've setup some `Endpoints` (80 for Http and 443 for SSL) I am using the `CNAME` of `myvm.cloudapp.net` and I set the binding in the VM IIS to my Azure VM `INTERNAL IP ADDRESS`. Voila, it all works. The problem is that Azure will change this IP every once in a while...so my question is, is there a better way to set this up so that I don't have to worry about IP address changes?

The very helpful reply I got was about `"dynamic DNS"`

However, this only deals with a part of the problem. The second part is the `Bindings` inside of `IIS` on the `Azure` server, how to I make sure those always have the correct IP?

Comment: Wouldn't setting the binding to "All Unassigned" (which should be the default) take care of this?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to setup a virtual network in Azure prior to provisioning the Virtual Machine.  This will give you a set of internal IPs to map your sites in IIS.

Then, follow the instructions in this article to do what you are asking:

[Configuring a custom domain name for a Windows Azure cloud service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/)

I  currently have a physical server running several web sites but I plan to move them to a new virtual machine in Azure so I setup a few sites on a test VM.

My Azure subscription is currently running on an MSDN account that gives me $100 per month free.  Recently while testing other Azure services, I went over the $100 credit amount and my subscription was disabled.  This seems to have caused my orignial public IP address to be recycled.  When I recieved my next set of monthly credit dollars, my subscription re-enabled but my IP had changed.  I had to go back into DNS and change my A records to the new external IP address.

I am not sure if there is a way to retain an IP address in a situation like this but be aware of that type of scenario.

Hope this helps,
Brian

Comment: The problem is that this external IP address change can happen anytime and for any reason...this is the whole reason for my post...

Answer (score 1):

Rather belatedly - Azure does now offer "[Reserved IP Addresses](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/)", which may help - however because of the use case you're after they may not help:

The [pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/ip-addresses/) of these is currently<sup>1</sup> listed as:

> First 5 Reserved IP addresses **(in use)**
>   £0 per hour per IP
>
> **Unused** Reserved IP addresses
>   £0.0025 per hour per IP (~£2/month per IP)

And an unused IP address is defined as (emphasis added):

> [...] a Reserved IP address that isn't used in a **running** deployment

So if you turn off a VM that is using a reserved IP, that IP becomes "unused", and you'll start being charged for it - however if your VMs are disabled because you're out of credit you won't have any credit to pay for the reserved IPs either.